# git post-receive hook "empty ident name"

Tags: git, gitlab

I have built the following post-receive hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/node/heartbeat/ || exit
unset GIT_DIR
echo $USER
git pull --no-edit
```

When I'm pushing to the repository the following error is returned:

```
remote:
remote: From server.net:chris/heartbeat
remote:    c0df678..5378ade  master     -> origin/master
remote:
remote: *** Please tell me who you are.
remote:
remote: Run
remote:
remote:   git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
remote:   git config --global user.name "Your Name"
remote:
remote: to set your account's default identity.
remote: Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
remote:
remote: fatal: empty ident name (for <git@server.net>) not allowed
```

When running git config -l from the git user:

```
user.name=server
user.email=server@server.com
core.autocrlf=input
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
remote.origin.url=git@server.net:chris/heartbeat.git
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

I don't understand why it's still thinking that my user.email and user.name are empty as git config -l tells me it's not. Does anyone know a solution/workaround for this problem?

Comment: Are you running the `git config` on the server side (the "remote" side)? And where is the `echo $USER` result in your trace?

Comment: Yes, I am running git config on the server side and the result of echo $USER is the first blank line of the error.

Comment: If you replace that `echo` by an `id -a`, would you get '`git`' as a result? Is the hook executed by the user `git`?

Comment: The following line is returned, so it is executed by the git user.
remote: uid=1000(git) gid=1000(git) groups=1000(git)

The strange thing also is that when I execute the hook manually after a su git no errors are returned.

Comment: And, still in that hook, what a `git config --local -l` would return?

Comment: So no user.name or user.email are found then. What is the right way to set it locally for the git user?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To make sure this work, a `git config --local -l` needs to return the user name and email.

If it doesn't, go to that repo on the server, and type;:

```
git config user.name server
git config user.email server@server.com
```

Comment: oh my god finally. Been writing this commit script in node.js for two days. Thanks a lot! But couldn't commit because the author was never there, even though servers user did have global credintials. Good now.

Comment: @wytten what git version are you using? On which OS? in a shell or a CMD session? What command did you type? Did you put the two '-' in front of local?

Comment: @VonC Linux git 1.7.1 'git config --local -l' thanks

Comment: 1.7.1 is ancient, but I believe this option should have worked. Still, if you can upgrade, that would be best. (http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170831/7490)

Comment: Why is it not working ? The name and email are correctly registered in the global config

Comment: @la_urre You could ask a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

my git version is git 1.7.1 (centos 6.8);
Of course , i can not use "git config --local -l"

My final solution：

goto the  git code server 
then goto your home/www/your projecet/.git/ folder to modify the config like

```
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = true
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = /home/git/repos/music.git
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
[user]
name = server
email = server@minstech.cn
```

name = server

email = server@minstech.cn

is be added

Comment: thank you so much, nothing else helped. I've added those lines into `.git/config` on hosting and the hook finally worked

Answer (score -1):

You should also unset:

```
GIT_COMMITER_NAME
GIT_COMMITER_EMAIL
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
```

Comment: I agree. The above environment variables override the ones set in `git config --local -l`. If they are set to empty strings the `fatal: empty ident name` error will still occur. You can see if they're populated with `env | grep GIT_` and use `unset` to remove them.