# git-am not reading configuration correctly

Tags: git, git-config

It appears that `git am --continue` is not reading my configuration correctly.

```
git am --continue 
Applying: 
fatal: empty ident name (for <>) notallowed
```

I tried following the advice in
[git post-receive hook "empty ident name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24850247/git-post-receive-hook-empty-ident-name).  Initially `user.name` and `user.email` were correct when running `git config --global -l`.  I followed the advice in the previous question so the exact same values are also returned for `git config --local -l`.

I find it strange that `(for <>)` is in the error message.  From the configuration in mentioned question, it looks like `remote.origin.url` is being ignored.

My setup works flawlessly otherwise.  This is the first time I've run into this type of error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I think the fact `git am` ignores the global configuration values is by design - the commit should have the the name/email of the patch author, not yours.

Instead, when continuing, `git am` reads this information from the file `.git/rebase-apply/author-script`, which should have been filled with the correct values by `git mailinfo` before stopping:

```
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='Committer'
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='email@example.org'
GIT_AUTHOR_DATE='Thu, 28 Apr 2016 11:38:59 -0700'
```

Most likely, the applied `.patch`-file was not correctly formatted (i.e. missing `From:` and `Date:` lines), so that `git mailinfo` wasn't able to figure out these values.

You can enter them manually and then run `git am --continue` to continue with the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Another case where git am might ignore the name: Git historically rejected a very short string as an author name while accepting a patch e-mail.

Git 2.33 (Q3 2021) fixes that.

See [commit 72ee47c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/72ee47ceebc7d3ddbd31942b28f9fe47f00b0540) (16 May 2021) by [edef (`edef1c`)](https://github.com/edef1c).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 26b25e0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26b25e03b204548d08fd6a284f24c65ef2cbcba0), 10 Jun 2021)</sup>

> ### [`mailinfo`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/72ee47ceebc7d3ddbd31942b28f9fe47f00b0540): don't discard names under 3 characters
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: edef</sup>

> I sometimes receive patches from people with short mononyms, and in my cultural environment these are not uncommon (as seen in "[Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)").
> To my dismay, [`git-am`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/72ee47ceebc7d3ddbd31942b28f9fe47f00b0540/Documentation/git-am.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am))</sup> currently discards their names, and replaces them with their email addresses.