# Getting 'fatal: empty ident name not allowed' when doing 'Git commit --amend'

Tags: git

I am doing a `git commit --amend` and I get this error:

> fatal: empty ident name (for <>) not allowed

I've found a bunch of stuff saying I need to set my `user.email` and `user.name`, but I have. This is the the result when I do a `git config --global --list`:

> core.exludesfile=/home/dzou/.gitignore
> core.editor=vim
> user.email=dzou@company.com
> user.name=dzou

What is going on here?

Comment: Configure your git username and email

Comment: I note that your `git config --global --list` output includes a setting for `core.exludesfile`. This is missing a `c`, it should read `core.excludesfile`. Be wary of typos: one letter wrong changes a word! :-)

Comment: @torek yup, thanks!

Comment: I was having a similar error, but for `git am --continue`. Manually setting the user/email in `.git/rebase-apply/author-script` solved it for me (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38836157/3345085).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Set global `user.name` and `user.email` first by order like below.

```
$ git config --global user.name "dzou"
$ git config --global user.email "dzou@company.com"
```

**NB:** careful, use double quote instead of single quotes

Comment: I had already done that before, but it didn't work. I just did it again, and it now works. What happened? Thanks!

Comment: So I looked in my history and the previous commands I ran didn't have quotes around my name/email or they had single quotes around my name/email. That's probably why it wasn't working.

Comment: the above answer did the trick for me. Didn't know that I need to set username first before setting user email. Ty!

Comment: @claudios FWIW my Git client recommends running `git config --global user.email "you@example.com"` and then `git config --global user.name "Your Name"` and yours probably does too.

Comment: @dippas, I did this and still get the error described in the question. Any ideas?

Comment: @ChaseHardin have you read the above comments carefully? they might help you as well or the below answers

Comment: @dippas yes I've read and tried the other comments. I figured running `git config --global user.name "FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME"` and `git config --global user.email "MY_NAME@example.com"` would've resolved it.  When running `git config --local -e` I see my username/email

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar problem because when I committed, the `user.email` was set correctly but `user.name` was empty. So even if I set the user name in the config, still I've got the same "empty ident" error.

I fixed it adding `--reset-author` to the amend command (after setting the correct `user.name`)

```
$ git commit --amend --reset-author
```

Comment: This seems like the best answer considering the "symptoms" of the question. I had the same issue with the `fatal: empty ident name (for <Olov@<mycomp>.localdomain>) not allowed` message, also after setting the username and email address. So one part of the issue lied there (that's the obvious part), but this part with the `--reset-author` was what I was missing.

Comment: What I find weird though, is that I was able to do a simple `commit` without setting any username or email, and that's when the commit ident name became `<Olov@<mycomp>.localdomain>`. But when doing a `commit --amend`, the error message appeared.

Comment: Well well. What do you know... this seemed to be the least promising of all the answers, but, after all, it did the job! Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 10):

Fixed it by deleting *local* config and using the global configuration

```
$ git config --local -e
```

now delete all local lines and save the empty file

Comment: exactly that was my issue. Although the global configuration was set, the local one had an empty name and email.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone that comes later, I had a similar problem but even after setting local and global config I was getting the same error.

My problem was that I had this in ~/.bashrc

```
export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=""
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=""
```

These variables override the other settings. I forgot that I had done it precisely to stop people from trying to commit from the production server :)

The tricky bit is that I have git 1.7.1 on that server and env variables don't show up with

```
git config --list
```

The fix was to set values for those variables which is valid only for a session (and exactly what I needed).

```
export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="RaiderOfTheLostBBS"
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="email@example.com"
```

Answer (score 7):

A local setting can easily override the global settings! Just had this happen to me - *while I did a really dirty fix using someone elses repo*.

`$ git config --local -e`

let's you remove or change the local values that disturb your commit!

Comment: I ended up using this approach after the others failed. In my case, my user.name was defined correctly globally but in my local config I had an extra user.name entry which was empty at the bottom of the file that was causing the error.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem after doing some filter-branch without using quotes too. That created a new user without any information hence the error, so the suggestion of configuring your own user name and email won't help.

I manged to fix it by editing the config file and removing the empty user. You can run

```
$ git config --global -e
```

and deleting the `[user]` line that doesn't have any member field. I had to do a reboot too but it works after that. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

In case someone still needs help with this. What I did was, I entered my name as the user.name instead of the email and it worked.

```
git config --global user.name Kunle
```

Comment: this is the answer, which helped me! thanks

Answer (score 1):

vi .git/config

Edit the missing user name or email values in the file and save it.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the response by "Raider of the lost BBS" (which I can't reply to, due to insufficient reputation points), but I was on a shared system, which did not have `user.email` or `user.name` set.  I tried:
`export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Firstname Lastname"` and
`export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="first.last@org.org"` and then `git commit --author="Firstname Lastname <first.last@org.org>"`.  This still produced an error that included `Committer identity unknown` and `fatal: empty ident name (for <otheruser@machine.edu>) not allowed` (details obfuscated, of course).  This was confusing, since I thought I was providing my identity twice, through the environment variables and the `author` flag.

Since editing either `~/.gitconfig` or `<repo>/.git/config` were not viable options, I kept at it and finally got it to work by setting:
`export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Firstname Lastname"` and
`export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="first.last@org.org"` (with `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` and `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` still set), then running the same commit command.  That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. let me know, if you are using git on Windows Operating System. Windows needs .Net Framework 4.8 to run git. so first install it first
2. clone your git repository: `git clone https://github.com/userName/yourRepo.git`
3. Open your repository folder
4. now run git-bash
5. type following commands
   `git config --global user.name "Your User name On Github"`

   `git config --global user.email "Your Registered Email on github"`

   `git config --global user.password "Your Github password"`

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and I solved by removing [user] stage in config file in .git folder in the repository

```
nano .git/config
```

Answer (score 0):

Create .gitconfig file in your $HOME path:

```
$ cat $HOME/.gitconfig
[user]
        name = daniel
        email = daniel@andrzejewski.it
[push]
        default = matching
        default = matching
```

With this file in place I stopped getting the error "fatal: empty ident name (for ...) not allowed"